# Adding a variable to the end of a filename in perl

Tags: perl

I am using open to wrtie to a file. But i have a declared variable which i want added to the filename. I have tried everything possible but it isn't working. I have a script with about 100 lines but I am pretty sure my variable isn't changing anywhere in the code.

```
my $env = "TEST";
some code;
open $file, '>>', 'filename_$env.txt' or die;
my code;
```

But everytime it's returning the $env but not the value appended to the filename. I tried it without the _, with the "" around the $env,`` around the $env, curlies etc..
What silly mistake am i doing?

Comment: you need "" quotes  # open $file, '>>', "filename_$env.txt" or die;

Comment: Did you really not use quotes around `TEST`?

Comment: I did. No issues with the variable decalaration in my code. I missed the quotes in the question. sorry.

Comment: @user3164754 You should always cut and paste code -- not type it in. Missing little details like that is a very bad thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use double quotes:

```
open $file, '>>', "filename_$env.txt" or die;
```

Single quotes would prevent variable expansion.

Also, saying:

```
open $file, '>>', "filename_${env}.txt" or die;
```

would prevent any ambiguity if you have similar variable names.

Comment: Wow..Who would have thunk it? I tried everything. Actually I achived the result by using . to concatenate the name and the env variable. Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: Well, apparently you tried everything short of [reading the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors) :-)